# How to display all month names if data doesn't exist in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display all the month names with the value of zero if the data doesn't exist in the MySQL database.

For example

Table: **invoice_order**

```
order_id | user_id    | order_date | order_total_amount
1        | 1          | 01-01-2021 | 10000
2        | 1          | 02-02-2021 | 20000
```

MySQL Query

```
$query = "
select date_format(order_date,'%M')
     , sum(order_total_amount) 
  from invoice_order 
 where user_id = '$user_id' 
 group 
    by year(order_date)
     , month(order_date) 
 order 
    by year(order_date)
     , month(order_date)
";
```

The above query would return *January* and *February* along with their respective order amount. But what I'm trying to do is to return all the month's names with the value of 0 if data does not exist in the table.

@björn-büttner this is for you. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
$sale_months = array("January"=>0,"February"=>0,"March"=>0,"April"=>0,"May"=>0,"June"=>0,"July"=>0,"August"=>0,"September"=>0,"October"=>0,"November"=>0,"December"=>0);  

$sale = "select date_format(order_date,'%M'), sum(order_total_amount) from invoice_order where user_id='$user_id' group by year(order_date),month(order_date) order by year(order_date),month(order_date)";

$sale_query = mysqli_query($connection,$sale);
$sale_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sale_query);

foreach($sale_result as $row) {
    $sale_months[$row[0]] = $sale_months[$row[1]];
}
```

print_r($sale_result);
This would return the Array ( [date_format(order_date,'%M')] => January [sum(order_total_amount)] => 40000 ) 1

Comment: You cannot display DB data if it doesn't exist, use PHP to fulfill the gap.

Comment: Technically, you could write a slightly convoluted query to achieve this, but I personally feel it'd be cleaner to do in PHP, inside the displaying script.

Comment: As an aside - depending upon where and how you derive the `$user_id` variable you are potentially at risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Could you please answer how we can achieve this using PHP @biesior

Comment: I'm getting the value of $user_id using session @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: No, I can't, SO is not *write it for me* service.  This job is on basic level and you **must** write such things yourself.  Tip just use the loop from 1 to 12 to fill the new created array. If data exists in Db add its  value.  Otherwise add 0. Year has fixed number of months so there's no place for mistake. That's 30 seconds craft.

Comment: Figured it out! I am able to achieve the result using SQL. but unable to achieve the same result using PHP. I answered the question in the interest of other noobies like me  @biesior

Answer (score -1):

why not use `date()` on php-side to create an array with 0 prefilled and then just filling the months with something else that are returned from the database? Or just have the months hardcoded there?

```php
$months= array("January"=>0,"February"=>0);

foreach($query->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $months[$row[0]] = $months[$row[1]];
}
```

Comment: I just tried this method but it didn't work. I updated the question for you, Could you please see what am I doing wrong? Thank you @björn-büttner

Comment: using `$sale_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sale_query);` will only return a single row, you need to iterate through all rows

Comment: Got it! As biesior mentioned, I need to use the loop from 1 to 12

Comment: You should update your answer! So it could help others too (noobies like me). Don't know why did someone downvote your answer @björn-büttner

Answer (score -1):

Credit:- [Select query to results all 12 months even if data not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405663/select-query-to-results-all-12-months-even-if-data-not-exist)

Worked perfectly

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
    SUM(IF(month = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'May',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        MIN(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b')) AS month,
            SUM(order_total_amount) AS total
    FROM
        invoice_order
    WHERE
        user_id = '1'
    GROUP BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)) AS sale
```