# Select query to results all 12 months even if data not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch out all month names with the value of zero if data does not exist.

Here is what I achieved so far

invoice_order table

```
order_id | user_id    | order_date | order_total_amount
1        | 1          | 01-01-2021 | 10000
2        | 1          | 02-02-2021 | 20000
```

The SQL query would pick the order_total_amount of the first row (10000) which would store in January month. but for February, it is showing order_total_amount zero

value zero needs to show up only when no data exists

```
$monthly_sale = "SELECT 
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
    SUM(IF(month = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'May',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
    SUM(IF(month = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'
    FROM (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%M') AS month, SUM(order_total_amount) as total
FROM invoice_order
WHERE user_id='$user_id' group by year(order_date),month(order_date) order by year(order_date),month(order_date)) as sale";
```

the above query would return all month names along with zero value (if data doesn't exist). but it showing order_total_amount of only the first row. To make it more simplified, it picking up the order amount of only one month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type you need date_FORMAt &b for your query

But your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so instead of inserting the $user_id use **prepared statements with parameters** see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE invoice_order (user_id int,order_date date, order_total_amount DECIMAL(10,2))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO invoice_order VALUES 
> (1,'2020-01-01',10.1),(1,'2020-02-01',10.1),(1,'2020-03-01',10.1),
> (1,'2020-01-04',10.1),(1,'2020-05-01',10.1),(1,'2020-06-01',10.1),
> (1,'2020-07-01',10.1),(1,'2020-08-01',10.1),(1,'2020-09-01',10.1),
> (1,'2020-10-01',10.1),(1,'2020-11-01',10.1),(1,'2020-12-01',10.1),
> (1,'2021-01-01',10.1),(1,'2021-02-01',10.1),(1,'2021-03-01',10.1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>         MIN(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b')) AS month,
>             SUM(order_total_amount) AS total
>     FROM
>         invoice_order
>     WHERE
>         user_id = '1'
>     GROUP BY  MONTH(order_date)
>     ORDER BY MONTH(order_date)
> ```
>
> ```
> month | total
> :---- | ----:
> Jan   | 30.30
> Feb   | 20.20
> Mar   | 20.20
> May   | 10.10
> Jun   | 10.10
> Jul   | 10.10
> Aug   | 10.10
> Sep   | 10.10
> Oct   | 10.10
> Nov   | 10.10
> Dec   | 10.10
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'May',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
>     SUM(IF(month = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         MIN(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b')) AS month,
>             SUM(order_total_amount) AS total
>     FROM
>         invoice_order
>     WHERE
>         user_id = '1'
>     GROUP BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)
>     ORDER BY YEAR(order_date) , MONTH(order_date)) AS sale
> ```

> ```
>   Jan |   Feb |   Mar |  Apr |   May |   Jun |   Jul |   Aug |   Sep |   Oct |   Nov |   Dec
> ----: | ----: | ----: | ---: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----:
> 30.30 | 20.20 | 20.20 | 0.00 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10 | 10.10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5832e40006b0ad9683572218b2723a18)*

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work! Now it is not even picking up the value ($order_total_amount) of the first row

Comment: have you some sample data, it should work.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I updated the question. Can you check the question again @nbk

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank you so much! @nbk

Comment: @ShaktiGoyal don't forget the part about sql injection

Comment: Yes, this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: yes it is bcause it is varchar an int 0 would not be displayed

Comment: Got it! So I just have to change the datatype from varchar to int! Thank you

Comment: Just changed the data type! But it is still showing the bar despite having 0 value! Weird

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT year(order_date),
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 1 THEN order_total_amount ELSE 0 END) as JAN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 2 THEN order_total_amount ELSE 0 END) as FEB,
       . . . 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 12 THEN order_total_amount ELSE 0 END) as DEC
FROM invoice_order ii
WHERE user_id = ?
GROUP BY year(order_date)
ORDER BY year(order_date);
```

Notes:

- There is no need for a subquery.
- There is a handy `MONTH()` function which returns the month number.
- Don't put column aliases in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for date and time constants.
- Pass the user id in as a *parameter*.  **Don't munge query strings with constant values.**

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Sorry did not see the MySQL tag. This is a SQL Server solution. I will leave for that intended use case.**

I like using a cross apply with a numbers table (i chose a while loop for ease to create this) for something like this.

```
create table #t(m int)

create table #invoiceOrder(orderDate date, order_total_amount money)

insert into #invoiceOrder
values
('1/1/2020' , 10.5)

declare @i int = 1
while (@i<13)
begin 
    insert into #t values(@i)
    select @i=@i+1
end

select m,sum(case when month(io.orderDate)=m then io.order_total_amount else 0 end )
from #invoiceOrder io
cross apply (select m from #t) t
group by m

drop table #t,#invoiceOrder
```

Comment: The question appears to be about MySQL